# Блокировка сайта через hosts не работает, если файл изменить через .bat-файл. (Даже запущенный от имени администратора)

Tags: windows, bat, hosts

Если запустить notepad.exe от имени администратора и открыть в нем файл hosts, а затем прописать туда, допустим, `127.0.0.1 vk.com` то это будет работать.

Ниже я скинул алгоритм работы батника, который нужно запустить от имени администратора, после чего в файл hosts можно точно также внести изменения и сохранить его. Запись в файле успешно сохраняется, но браузер почему-то игнорирует ее. Даже после перезапуска пк. С чем это связано?

```
echo off
notepad C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
pause
```

Comment: После редактирования чё показывает `type C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`?

Comment: выводит содержимое файла, вместе со строкой `127.0.0.1 vk.com`

Comment: Ну значит браузер кладёт на hosts. Не удивлён. Тебе тогда дорога в proxy, firewall.